# Assigning a Project Level Parameter to a variable in BIMLScript

Tags: ssis, biml

I am attempting to read a project.params parameter in bimlscript. I have tried from what I could tell is the proper syntax `<# var env = @[$Project::Environment]#>`but I keep getting an error "Keyword, identifier, or string expected after verbatim specifier: @"

Can someone please enlighten me on the proper way to do this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a sample package Biml of

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <Packages>
        <Package Name="so_59375738" >
            <Parameters>
                <Parameter Name="Environment" DataType="Int32">1</Parameter>
            </Parameters>
        </Package>
    </Packages>
</Biml>
```

What we need to do is access the package's Parameters collection to obtain our Parameter and from there, we can use the `.Value` property to obtain the initialized value.

The other thing to note is that we must use tiering here as accessing the RootNode in the same tier that the package is created won't work. For the exceedingly technical minded, the explicit tier here is not required as the sample above is static Biml which is always Tier 0 and dynamic Biml aka BimlScript will default to Tier 1. But I favor being explicit in my intentions

```
<#@ template tier="999" #>
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
<#
foreach(AstPackageNode p in this.RootNode.Packages)
{
    foreach(var pm in p.Parameters)
    {
        WriteLine(string.Format("<!-- {0}:{1}->{2} -->", p.Name, pm.Name, pm.Value));
    }
}

// Explicit approach
WriteLine(string.Format("<!-- {0}:{1}->{2} -->", this.RootNode.Packages["so_59375738"], this.RootNode.Packages["so_59375738"].Parameters["Environment"].Name, this.RootNode.Packages["so_59375738"].Parameters["Environment"].Value));

#>
</Biml>
```

Presumably, when the package (so_59375738) was built out, we knew what the parameter `Environment` was initialized to from our metadata repository so in my mind, it'd be cleaner to go back to the repository and access the value from there.

Unless this is an effort to identify, document and rework existing product then yes, clearly you won't have the original metastore to access.

Comment: And in case it wasn't 1000% obvious, your code would be `var env = pm.Value;` in the first example where I'm printing comments